# Derive a while loop (which seemingly have some logarithmic traits) runs in $\Theta(n)$

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, big-o-notation

I know for a fact that algorithm **A** runs in $\Theta(n)$, but how does one derive that?

Algorithm **A**

```
i = 1
while i ≤ n
  s = 0
  while s ≤ i
    s = s + 1
  i = 2 ∗ i
```

The inner loop is clearly $O(i)$ (linear time).

The outer loop is clearly $O(\log n)$ (logarithmic time).

A visualitation of the loop in terms of an input $n$ would look as follows:

[image]
, the black lines represents the amount of work or iterations required in terms of $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^k 2^i=\Theta(2^k)$ and you have $k\approx\log n$, so the sum is $\Theta(2^{\log n})=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: I am sorry, could you elaborate a little on your answer? I am not following your reasoning.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? The sum is the total amount of time spent in the inner loop if the outer loop executes $k$ times.

Comment: Okay, so the inner loop runs $\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^i=2+4+8+...+k$ times ... I get that. First off, that summation is equal to $2^{k+1}-1$. As far as I am concerned, $2^{k+1}-1 \neq \Theta(2^k)$.

What do you have to say about that?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen I say that, for all $k\geq 0$, $1\times 2^k\leq 2^{k+1}-1 < 2\times 2^k$ so $2^{k+1}=\Theta(2^k)$.

Comment: "*$k$ is the total amount of time spent in the inner loop if the outer loop executes $k$ times*", which is $k\approx \log n$ ... okay, so why isn't this $\log n$ the answer (the time complexity)? Why did you (this is what I assume you did) substitute $k$ in the term $2^k$ with $\log n$ to get $Theta(2^{\log n})$? You just found out how many times the inner loop executes in terms of $n$ ... why isn't this the answer ($k\approx \log n$)?

Comment: No, _the sum_ $\sum_{i=1}^k 2^i$ is the total amount of time spent in the inner loop if the outer loop executes $k$ times.

Comment: yeah, sorry, $\sum_{i=1}^{k} =\Theta(2^k)$ is the time spent in the inner loop. Isolate $k$, and we have $k = \log n$. Well okay, my question still remains. Why isn't this the complexity of the entire loop? Since this is only the run time of the inner loop, how is the runtime of the entire loop derived?

Comment: Because the inner loop executes some number of times every time the outer loops executes. So the total running time is the total time spent in all of the loops.